# InitializeSecurityContext returned code= -2146892963

Tags: .net, web-services, diffie-hellman

I have an asmx webservice that consumes hundreds of other webservices from other companies. Each webservice is expected to return data in a very specific format (we provide a wsdl for the companies to use). I recently started encountering an error with two companies we communicate with. The error ended up being the very generic "The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..", so I turned on logging in our webservice.

Here is the portion of the log around the error:

```
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Data from Socket#39875033::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000000 : 16 03 01 16  86                                  : .....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Exiting Socket#39875033::Receive()  -> Int32#5
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Socket#39875033::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Data from Socket#39875033::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] (printing 1024 out of 1375)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000005 : 02 00 00 4D 03 01 58 6F-CE 68 54 44 73 EB F6 F5 : ...M..Xo.hTDs...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000015 : BC E0 22 AF C8 A2 52 CA-86 CD F7 6D BA 97 33 CD : .."...R....m..3.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000025 : B6 50 E0 0A 59 4C 20 58-6F CE 68 8A FB B6 30 54 : .P..YL Xo.h...0T
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000035 : 9A 23 CE 4D 5A A3 2A 75-DF A2 4C A7 16 36 DD FA : .#.MZ.*u..L..6..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000045 : 26 64 5E 64 FF 7B 97 00-39 00 00 05 FF 01 00 01 : &d^d.{..9.......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000055 : 00 0B 00 13 F8 00 13 F5-00 05 4A 30 82 05 46 30 : ..........J0..F0
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000065 : 82 04 2E A0 03 02 01 02-02 04 50 D3 24 53 30 0D : ..........P.$S0.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000075 : 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D-01 01 0B 05 00 30 81 BA : ..*.H........0..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000085 : 31 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04-06 13 02 55 53 31 16 30 : 1.0...U....US1.0
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000095 : 14 06 03 55 04 0A 13 0D-45 6E 74 72 75 73 74 2C : ...U....Entrust,
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000000A5 : 20 49 6E 63 2E 31 28 30-26 06 03 55 04 0B 13 1F :  Inc.1(0&..U....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000000B5 : 53 65 65 20 77 77 77 2E-65 6E 74 72 75 73 74 2E : See www.entrust.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000000C5 : 6E 65 74 2F 6C 65 67 61-6C 2D 74 65 72 6D 73 31 : net/legal-terms1
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000000D5 : 39 30 37 06 03 55 04 0B-13 30 28 63 29 20 32 30 : 907..U...0(c) 20
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000000E5 : 31 32 20 45 6E 74 72 75-73 74 2C 20 49 6E 63 2E : 12 Entrust, Inc.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000000F5 : 20 2D 20 66 6F 72 20 61-75 74 68 6F 72 69 7A 65 :  - for authorize
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000105 : 64 20 75 73 65 20 6F 6E-6C 79 31 2E 30 2C 06 03 : d use only1.0,..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000115 : 55 04 03 13 25 45 6E 74-72 75 73 74 20 43 65 72 : U...%Entrust Cer
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000125 : 74 69 66 69 63 61 74 69-6F 6E 20 41 75 74 68 6F : tification Autho
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000135 : 72 69 74 79 20 2D 20 4C-31 4B 30 1E 17 0D 31 35 : rity - L1K0...15
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000145 : 30 31 33 30 31 31 33 30-34 33 5A 17 0D 31 38 30 : 0130113043Z..180
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000155 : 34 32 39 31 38 30 35 33-37 5A 30 7E 31 0B 30 09 : 429180537Z0~1.0.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000165 : 06 03 55 04 06 13 02 55-53 31 11 30 0F 06 03 55 : ..U....US1.0...U
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000175 : 04 08 13 08 49 6C 6C 69-6E 6F 69 73 31 13 30 11 : ....Illinois1.0.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000185 : 06 03 55 04 07 13 0A 4E-6F 72 74 68 62 72 6F 6F : ..U....Northbroo
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000195 : FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 55-04 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF : k1#0!..U....Goog
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000001A5 : FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 73-75 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF : le12 SafesearchC
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000001B5 : FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 22-30 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF : ompany1"0 ..U...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000001C5 : FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 64-34 FF FF FF FF FF FF FF : .bot-gad4-c6c.go
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000001D5 : FF FF FF FF FF FF FF 63-6F 6D 30 82 01 22 30 0D : ogle12.com0.."0.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000001E5 : 06 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D-01 01 01 05 00 03 82 01 : ..*.H...........
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000001F5 : 0F 00 30 82 01 0A 02 82-01 01 00 B2 52 E7 42 40 : ..0.........R.B@
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000205 : 49 91 1D D3 F2 F5 D3 60-3B A8 32 A1 CF A9 6A F0 : I......`;.2...j.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000215 : B8 29 2B EF 5E B9 66 9B-9A 6A 39 19 86 54 1C 56 : .)+.^.f..j9..T.V
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000225 : E9 14 7E 1C BB D1 A2 B3-8B C5 BE 27 10 EE 38 DB : ..~........'..8.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000235 : DC AC 89 F2 81 FC 96 8A-B0 8E D6 98 F5 96 5D 1C : ..............].
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000245 : B6 79 E0 1D 2D C3 75 38-3B F1 20 FB 07 3A 9A B3 : .y..-.u8;. ..:..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000255 : 41 5E DC 8F 32 04 D1 46-07 06 89 DB 4D 32 DB B7 : A^..2..F....M2..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000265 : 8A 16 70 FD 90 74 92 B7-05 73 E7 AD B4 72 CC 4C : ..p..t...s...r.L
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000275 : A4 49 35 31 8D 8E 53 68-2A 4B 4E 7A D8 5D EF 1A : .I51..Sh*KNz.]..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000285 : 4D 0C F6 83 51 CC 5C 65-1C A5 D0 6D 71 AC C9 62 : M...Q.\e...mq..b
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000295 : 6C F8 82 90 02 63 27 BE-65 F5 BF 55 68 38 9C 6A : l....c'.e..Uh8.j
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000002A5 : 04 7A 35 C6 BC 69 12 84-6C 5E BF 3A 32 84 F6 E4 : .z5..i..l^.:2...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000002B5 : 14 6D 8E 4E D0 FC B9 72-90 D2 06 76 6A 4B 8A 81 : .m.N...r...vjK..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000002C5 : DB 14 B2 5B DE EE 9C A2-B2 81 84 EB 4C D7 13 0E : ...[........L...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000002D5 : C3 2E 69 40 6C BC FE E7-BC 97 FC 87 7A 61 6B C1 : ..i@l.......zak.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000002E5 : A7 A1 68 9F 71 4C 6B C3-98 6B 2C 6F E5 C1 64 14 : ..h.qLk..k,o..d.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000002F5 : 0C 63 DE 17 71 58 7A C8-4E D7 4D 02 03 01 00 01 : .c..qXz.N.M.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000305 : A3 82 01 8D 30 82 01 89-30 0B 06 03 55 1D 0F 04 : ....0...0...U...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000315 : 04 03 02 05 A0 30 1D 06-03 55 1D 25 04 16 30 14 : .....0...U.%..0.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000325 : 06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07-03 01 06 08 2B 06 01 05 : ..+.........+...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000335 : 05 07 03 02 30 33 06 03-55 1D 1F 04 2C 30 2A 30 : ....03..U...,0*0
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000345 : 28 A0 26 A0 24 86 22 68-74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 63 72 : (.&.$."http://cr
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000355 : 6C 2E 65 6E 74 72 75 73-74 2E 6E 65 74 2F 6C 65 : l.entrust.net/le
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000365 : 76 65 6C 31 6B 2E 63 72-6C 30 4B 06 03 55 1D 20 : vel1k.crl0K..U. 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000375 : 04 44 30 42 30 36 06 0A-60 86 48 01 86 FA 6C 0A : .D0B06..`.H...l.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000385 : 01 05 30 28 30 26 06 08-2B 06 01 05 05 07 02 01 : ..0(0&..+.......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000395 : 16 1A 68 74 74 70 3A 2F-2F 77 77 77 2E 65 6E 74 : ..http://www.ent
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000003A5 : 72 75 73 74 2E 6E 65 74-2F 72 70 61 30 08 06 06 : rust.net/rpa0...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000003B5 : 67 81 0C 01 02 02 30 68-06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 : g.....0h..+.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000003C5 : 01 01 04 5C 30 5A 30 23-06 08 2B 06 01 05 05 07 : ...\0Z0#..+.....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000003D5 : 30 01 86 17 68 74 74 70-3A 2F 2F 6F 63 73 70 2E : 0...http://ocsp.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000003E5 : 65 6E 74 72 75 73 74 2E-6E 65 74 30 33 06 08 2B : entrust.net03..+
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000003F5 : 06 01 05 05 07 30 02 86-27 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F : .....0..'http://
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Exiting Socket#39875033::Receive()  -> Int32#1375
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Socket#39875033::Receive()
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Data from Socket#39875033::Receive
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] (printing 1024 out of 4391)
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000564 : BB F6 5B 28 01 80 2C DE-DA 84 E1 3F 50 19 CA 7A : ..[(..,....?P..z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000574 : 75 41 AA 4B A7 D5 F9 94-81 EE 68 E9 72 E4 47 6A : uA.K......h.r.Gj
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000584 : 60 CF 92 1F 7B 34 E8 B3-2B 49 B8 CD 19 01 44 BC : `...{4..+I....D.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000594 : D7 5D 2A BF 95 A5 F3 7F-A3 6D CA C0 D4 E7 D7 87 : .]*......m......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000005A4 : 09 69 07 FE F2 47 00 05-07 30 82 05 03 30 82 03 : .i...G...0...0..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000005B4 : EB A0 03 02 01 02 02 04-51 D3 60 EE 30 0D 06 09 : ........Q.`.0...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000005C4 : 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01 01-0B 05 00 30 81 BE 31 0B : *.H........0..1.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000005D4 : 30 09 06 03 55 04 06 13-02 55 53 31 16 30 14 06 : 0...U....US1.0..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000005E4 : 03 55 04 0A 13 0D 45 6E-74 72 75 73 74 2C 20 49 : .U....Entrust, I    
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000005F4 : 6E 63 2E 31 28 30 26 06-03 55 04 0B 13 1F 53 65 : nc.1(0&..U....Se
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000604 : 65 20 77 77 77 2E 65 6E-74 72 75 73 74 2E 6E 65 : e www.entrust.ne
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000614 : 74 2F 6C 65 67 61 6C 2D-74 65 72 6D 73 31 39 30 : t/legal-terms190
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000624 : 37 06 03 55 04 0B 13 30-28 63 29 20 32 30 30 39 : 7..U...0(c) 2009
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000634 : 20 45 6E 74 72 75 73 74-2C 20 49 6E 63 2E 20 2D :  Entrust, Inc. -
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000644 : 20 66 6F 72 20 61 75 74-68 6F 72 69 7A 65 64 20 :  for authorized 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000654 : 75 73 65 20 6F 6E 6C 79-31 32 30 30 06 03 55 04 : use only1200..U.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000664 : 03 13 29 45 6E 74 72 75-73 74 20 52 6F 6F 74 20 : ..)Entrust Root 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000674 : 43 65 72 74 69 66 69 63-61 74 69 6F 6E 20 41 75 : Certification Au
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000684 : 74 68 6F 72 69 74 79 20-2D 20 47 32 30 1E 17 0D : thority - G20...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000694 : 31 34 31 30 32 32 31 37-30 35 31 34 5A 17 0D 32 : 141022170514Z..2
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000006A4 : 34 31 30 32 33 30 37 33-33 32 32 5A 30 81 BA 31 : 41023073322Z0..1
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000006B4 : 0B 30 09 06 03 55 04 06-13 02 55 53 31 16 30 14 : .0...U....US1.0.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000006C4 : 06 03 55 04 0A 13 0D 45-6E 74 72 75 73 74 2C 20 : ..U....Entrust, 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000006D4 : 49 6E 63 2E 31 28 30 26-06 03 55 04 0B 13 1F 53 : Inc.1(0&..U....S
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000006E4 : 65 65 20 77 77 77 2E 65-6E 74 72 75 73 74 2E 6E : ee www.entrust.n
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000006F4 : 65 74 2F 6C 65 67 61 6C-2D 74 65 72 6D 73 31 39 : et/legal-terms19
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000704 : 30 37 06 03 55 04 0B 13-30 28 63 29 20 32 30 31 : 07..U...0(c) 201
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000714 : 32 20 45 6E 74 72 75 73-74 2C 20 49 6E 63 2E 20 : 2 Entrust, Inc. 
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000724 : 2D 20 66 6F 72 20 61 75-74 68 6F 72 69 7A 65 64 : - for authorized
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000734 : 20 75 73 65 20 6F 6E 6C-79 31 2E 30 2C 06 03 55 :  use only1.0,..U
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000744 : 04 03 13 25 45 6E 74 72-75 73 74 20 43 65 72 74 : ...%Entrust Cert
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000754 : 69 66 69 63 61 74 69 6F-6E 20 41 75 74 68 6F 72 : ification Author
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000764 : 69 74 79 20 2D 20 4C 31-4B 30 82 01 22 30 0D 06 : ity - L1K0.."0..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000774 : 09 2A 86 48 86 F7 0D 01-01 01 05 00 03 82 01 0F : .*.H............
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000784 : 00 30 82 01 0A 02 82 01-01 00 DA 3F 96 D0 4D B9 : .0.........?..M.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000794 : 2F 44 E7 DB 39 5E 9B 50-EE 5C A5 61 DA 41 67 53 : /D..9^.P.\.a.AgS
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000007A4 : 09 AA 00 9A 8E 57 7F 29-6B DB C7 E1 21 24 AA 3A : .....W.)k...!$.:
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000007B4 : D0 8D 47 23 D2 ED 72 16-F0 91 21 D2 5D B7 B8 4B : ..G#..r...!.]..K
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000007C4 : A8 83 8F B7 91 32 68 CF-CE 25 93 2C B2 7D 97 C8 : .....2h..%.,.}..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000007D4 : FE C1 B4 17 BA 09 9E 03-90 93 7B 7C 49 83 22 68 : ..........{|I."h
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000007E4 : 8A 9B DE 47 C3 31 98 7A-2E 7D 40 0B D2 EF 3E D3 : ...G.1.z.}@...>.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000007F4 : B2 8C AA 8F 48 A9 FF 00-E8 29 58 06 F7 B6 93 5A : ....H....)X....Z
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000804 : 94 73 26 26 AD 58 0E E5-42 B8 D5 EA 73 79 64 68 : .s&&.X..B...sydh
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000814 : 53 25 B8 84 CF 94 7A AE-06 45 0C A3 6B 4D D0 C6 : S%....z..E..kM..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000824 : BE EA 18 A4 36 F0 92 B2-BA 1C 88 8F 3A 52 7F F7 : ....6.......:R..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000834 : 5E 6D 83 1C 9D F0 1F E5-C3 D6 DD A5 78 92 3D B0 : ^m..........x.=.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000844 : 6D 2C EA C9 CF 94 41 19-71 44 68 BA 47 3C 04 E9 : m,....A.qDh.G<..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000854 : 5D BA 3E F0 35 F7 15 B6-9E F2 2E 15 1E 3F 47 C8 : ].>.5........?G.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000864 : C8 38 A7 73 45 5D 4D B0-3B B1 8E 17 29 37 EA DD : .8.sE]M.;...)7..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000874 : 05 01 22 BB 94 36 2A 8D-5B 35 FE 53 19 2F 08 46 : .."..6*.[5.S./.F
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000884 : C1 2A B3 1A 62 1D 4E 2B-D9 1B 02 03 01 00 01 A3 : .*..b.N+........
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000894 : 82 01 09 30 82 01 05 30-0E 06 03 55 1D 0F 01 01 : ...0...0...U....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000008A4 : FF 04 04 03 02 01 06 30-0F 06 03 55 1D 13 04 08 : .......0...U....
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000008B4 : 30 06 01 01 FF 02 01 00-30 33 06 08 2B 06 01 05 : 0.......03..+...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000008C4 : 05 07 01 01 04 27 30 25-30 23 06 08 2B 06 01 05 : .....'0%0#..+...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000008D4 : 05 07 30 01 86 17 68 74-74 70 3A 2F 2F 6F 63 73 : ..0...http://ocs
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000008E4 : 70 2E 65 6E 74 72 75 73-74 2E 6E 65 74 30 30 06 : p.entrust.net00.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 000008F4 : 03 55 1D 1F 04 29 30 27-30 25 A0 23 A0 21 86 1F : .U...)0'0%.#.!..
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000904 : 68 74 74 70 3A 2F 2F 63-72 6C 2E 65 6E 74 72 75 : http://crl.entru
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000914 : 73 74 2E 6E 65 74 2F 67-32 63 61 2E 63 72 6C 30 : st.net/g2ca.crl0
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000924 : 3B 06 03 55 1D 20 04 34-30 32 30 30 06 04 55 1D : ;..U. .40200..U.
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000934 : 20 00 30 28 30 26 06 08-2B 06 01 05 05 07 02 01 :  .0(0&..+.......
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000944 : 16 1A 68 74 74 70 3A 2F-2F 77 77 77 2E 65 6E 74 : ..http://www.ent
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] 00000954 : 72 75 73 74 2E 6E 65 74-2F 72 70 61 30 1D 06 03 : rust.net/rpa0...
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Exiting Socket#39875033::Receive()  -> Int32#4391
System.Net Information: 0 : [10564] InitializeSecurityContext(credential = System.Net.SafeFreeCredential_SECURITY, context = 1d73b60:1c191a0, targetName = bot-gad4-c6c.google12.com, inFlags = ReplayDetect, SequenceDetect, Confidentiality, AllocateMemory, InitManualCredValidation)
System.Net Information: 0 : [10564] InitializeSecurityContext(In-Buffers count=2, Out-Buffer length=0, returned code=-2146892963).
System.Net.Sockets Verbose: 0 : [10564] Socket#39875033::Dispose()
System.Net Error: 0 : [10564] Exception in HttpWebRequest#54487120:: - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
System.Net Error: 0 : [10564] Exception in HttpWebRequest#54487120::GetResponse - The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel..
```

The returned code of -2146892963 is not in the list of enumerated returned codes for the InitializeSecurityContext method. Any idea what this means and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, after weeks of searching, I found out what the error code is.

My problem is the method was returning the code in decimal form and I should have been searching for the hex code, which is 8009035D. Searching for that error code resulted in this article: https://www.nsoftware.com/kb/xml/06101501.rst#8009035D, indicating that this particular error code could be related to Windows blocking weak security.

In my case, this is exactly what my problem was. I made the registry entry change given by the article, allowing for DHE Key length of 512 instead of the default 1024. After restarting the webserver, I was able to consume the company's webservice.

It turns out that this particular company was using a DHE key length of 768, resulting in the error.

As for fixing the problem, I feel the registry entry change should only be used to verify that this is the problem. I am currently in the process of updating this webservice to use TLS1.2, which seems to force the company to use a different algorithm.